# JPQL substring with regex

Tags: java, sql, regex, jpa, jpql

I have a table folder with rows like

```
id  |  path
1   | root
2   | root.first
3   | root.second
4   | root.first.child1
5   | root.first.child1.grandchild1
6   | root.first.child2
```

I have to fetch only the rows with path root.first.child1 and root.first.child2 but not root.first.child1.grandchild1
I can achieve this as native query  with substring like

```
select path from folder 
where substring (path from '((root.first\.)[^\.]+)?') is not null;
```

I am looking for an equivalent query in JPQL. substring in JPQL seems to be with index and a length but I couldn't get reference as to whether it can be used with regex pattern.

Comment: Depending on your database, you may not need to use substring. MySQL has a basic regex support that you can use `WHERE path REGEXP '^root\.first\.child[123]$'` and PostgreSQL uses shorthand `~` for case-sensitive POSIX regex and `~*` for case-insensitive, and also supports the SQL standard `SIMILAR TO`. Just go native and enjoy the minor performance tweak.

Comment: JPQL has LIKE which is the nearest thing. Other than that you go for native SQL functions invoked using JPQL "FUNCTION"

Comment: Thank you, the query is to be supported by postgres and oracle so using a db specific syntax is not helpful for me . So naitve  query is the option.

Comment: I just checked the JPA docs and they have `SUBSTRING(string, start[, end])` as their substring operation. Oracle doesn't seem have the standard `SIMILAR TO` operator, so maybe you should use `CREATE FUNCTION` on each database to create a universal proxy to `~` in PG and `REGEXP_LIKE` in Oracle.That would be a one-time operation for both.  From then on, they seem to be compatible enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no universal solution, however you can create a polyfill function in Postgres which will allow you to use POSIX regex on both servers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REGEXP_LIKE (IN input text, IN pattern text, IN flags varchar DEFAULT '')
RETURNS BOOLEAN
IMMUTABLE
COST 0.013
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN array_length(regexp_matches(input, pattern, flags), 1) > 0;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The cost is a rough measurement with real data.

With this you can use `REGEXP_LIKE` in both Oracle and PostgreSQL almost identically. `c`, `i` and `m` seem to be the only flags they both agree how they should work.